# Problem seeing shared drive when connected via 802.11ac

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina, with the current update of Yosemite, and I have an odd problem. To be honest, I'm not sure if it's laptop related, or somehow related to my router.

The issue is, when I am connected to my wireless network via 802.11ac, I can't see a shared drive that is connected to my router via ethernet. However, when connected via 802.11n, I can see it just fine.

For the sake of clarity, when I say "see my shared drive", I mean when I open Finder, I see the shared drive listed in the left hand menu under "Shared", I can navigate it's file system, etc.

My router is an Asus RT-AC68U, and the shared drive is a Bubba B3 (basically, a Debian based media server). This is frustrating, as I have to shut off 5 GHz on my router to do backups via Time Machine. Regardless of what protocol my MBP is using to connect, the laptop and the shared drive are on the same network, and in the same subnet. I can connect to the B3 via ssh, and I suppose I could just do a tar based, command line backup of my MBP and scp it over to the B3, but I'd really rather use Time Machine, as it does what it's supposed to do quite well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: when your Mac connect to Wi-Fi via 802.11ac, can you connect to the share directly(Finder, "go"->"Connect to server") even you can't see it in the "shared" list

Comment: No. Interestingly, the ip number is already listed in the field when I bring up "Connect to Server", but it timed out, and said the server may not exist or is unavailable, check your network, bla bla.

Comment: I am afraid this is a network issue. Compare to check what is different between 802.11c and 802.11n, IP address, router, proxy etc.

Comment: So your Bubba B3 is not 802.11ac capable and it wont report on that network.!

Answer (score 1):

The [Bubba B3 only supports 802.11 b/g/n](http://www.wegotserved.com/2010/11/18/hands-excito-b3-home-server/) networks by design.

That is why you do not see it on the 802.11ac network.

Comment: Even though it's connected via ethernet?